# webite mockup using photoshop

Tags: photoshop, mockups

Ive been asked to create a website mock-up using Photoshop, but I'm not sure what size to use for my canvas.

Please could you help me about that? or give me an advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard question as mostly websites are adaptive. From my experience I would say the height doesn't really matter if you allow scrolling, otherways I would take 700px for height. The width should be no more then 1200px.

Comment: thanks, so no rule or method to follow to have the best size?

Comment: Not really, nowadays a popular screen resolution is 1366x768 so I would take that as a starting point.

Comment: Tablet and smartphone users will *love* you for designing for 1366 x 768 screens.

Comment: That's a popular screen resolution? I've never owned a device with that screen resolution.

Comment: thanks Wooble. Well, the site is not so big i mean the home page. it will include only a gallery, side bar footer and header. if i choose 1200X800 it will be so big for the content.

Comment: 1366x768 is the size of full HD tablets or laptops i think

Comment: Many ultrabooks, 13-16" notbooks, tablets, ... use this resolution.

Comment: So Mr. Daan Pape, your advice is using 1366px as height and 768px for width ?

Comment: I would use 1200-1300 px for width and no more than 720px for height because you need to take in account the menu bars from the browser applications if you want to avoid scroll bars.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply suggest to stick with some grid framework, eg. 960.gs: http://960.gs/
You'll get a PSD grid to fit your design into and also CSS framework which you can use later for website coding.

Answer (score 0):

For a more up to date grid framework I suggest http://unsemantic.com/ since it allows for a responsive grid.